# android spotify ERROR detaching thread with interp frames (count=28)

Tags: android, android-ndk, spotify

I am doing an android project, and need to integrate Spotify streaming functionality.
Now I can load the dynamic libraries and call functions, but have some problems.

```
callbacks.notify_main_thread = callback_notify_main_thread;
config.callbacks = &callbacks;
error = sp_session_create(&config, &session);
```

Then in the callback function `notify_main_thread`, it will:

```
vm->AttachCurrentThread( &env, NULL );
vm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

This callback function is still in [native thread created by Spotify c code](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/faq/) (see question "According do documentation, some callbacks are called from 'internal session     thread'. What does that mean?").

So first I attach the current thread to javaVM and get JNIEnv, then call java methods, later detach it. But it will crash when executing `DetachCurrentThread`:

```
10-23 14:55:21.869: E/dalvikvm(1000): ERROR: detaching thread with interp frames (count=28)
10-23 14:55:21.869: I/dalvikvm(1000): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
10-23 14:55:21.869: I/dalvikvm(1000):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x40025ad8 self=0xcd80
10-23 14:55:21.869: I/dalvikvm(1000):   | sysTid=1000 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345017808
10-23 14:55:21.869: I/dalvikvm(1000):   | schedstat=( 523773188 356262213 1690 )
10-23 14:55:21.869: I/dalvikvm(1000):   at com.Spotify.Session.Initialise(Native Method)
...
10-23 14:55:21.869: E/dalvikvm(1000): VM aborting
10-23 14:55:21.899: D/RegisterService(519): insert plugin size 1
10-23 14:55:21.958: D/RegisterService(519): insert plugin size 1
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64): Build fingerprint: 'htc_wwe/htc_bravo/bravo/bravo:2.2.2/FRG83G/345208.14:user/release-keys'
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64): pid: 1000, tid: 1000  >>>  <<<
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadd00d
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  r0 00000026  r1 afd14699  r2 afd14699  r3 00000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  r4 808a3448  r5 808a3448  r6 fffe9544  r7 fffe2054
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  r8 80b09f04  r9 00000001  10 002f0980  fp 002f0980
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  ip deadd00d  sp beffb088  lr afd156e3  pc 80842560  cpsr 20000030
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d0  6472656767756265  d1  617453657669746e
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d2  4965746f67795a67  d3  6874654d2474690a
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d4  80a0a16580a0a179  d5  80a0a14580a0a155
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d6  80a0a12180a0a135  d7  0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d8  40b0000040a00000  d9  0000000000000005
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d16 001512f000000025  d17 bff0000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d18 3ff0000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d22 3ff0000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d24 3ff0000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d28 001f001f001f001e  d29 001e001f001f001f
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  d30 001f001f001f001f  d31 001f001f001f001f
10-23 14:55:21.979: I/DEBUG(64):  scr 60000012
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):          #00  pc 00042560  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):          #01  pc 0004fe6e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):          #02  pc 000455c2  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):          #03  pc 000088aa  /data/data/xxx/lib/xxx.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):          #04  pc 00008bb2  /data/data/xxx/lib/xxx.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):          #05  pc 0000a1e8  /data/data/xxx/lib/xxx.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): code around pc:
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): 80842540 20061861 f7d418a2 2000ea54 ebb2f7d4 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): 80842550 58234808 b1036bdb f8df4798 2026c01c 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): 80842560 0000f88c ec18f7d4 00060f0c fffe2054 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): 80842570 fffe52c8 000003a8 deadd00d f8dfb40e 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): 80842580 b503c02c bf00490a 188ba200 f853aa03 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): code around lr:
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): afd156c0 b5f74b0d 490da200 2600189b 585c4602 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): afd156d0 686768a5 f9b5e008 b120000c 46289201 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): afd156e0 9a014790 35544306 37fff117 6824d5f3 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): afd156f0 d1ed2c00 bdfe4630 0002cc60 000000d8 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): afd15700 b086b570 f602fb01 9004460c a804a901 
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): stack:
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb048  00000015  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb04c  afd146c9  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb050  afd425a0  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb054  afd4254c  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb058  00000000  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb05c  afd156e3  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb060  afd14699  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb064  afd14699  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb068  afd146f0  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb06c  808a3448  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb070  808a3448  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb074  fffe9544  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb078  fffe2054  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb07c  afd146fd  /system/lib/libc.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb080  df002777  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb084  e3a070ad  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): #00 beffb088  0000cd80  [heap]
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb08c  8084fe73  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64): #01 beffb090  0000cd80  [heap]
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb094  4635cdd8  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/2 (deleted)
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb098  0000cd80  [heap]
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb09c  00000001  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0a0  00000007  
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0a4  808494c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0a8  80b09f04  /data/data/xxx/lib/xxx.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0ac  80848655  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0b0  80b09aa8  /data/data/xxx/lib/xxx.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0b4  41a9e564  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0b8  808494c1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:21.999: I/DEBUG(64):     beffb0bc  808455c7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
10-23 14:55:22.239: I/ActivityManager(96): Process xxx (pid 1000) has died.
```

and if

```
//vm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

then sp_session_create() is called, it will never return an error code.

References:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/2H8z5grNqjo
2. http://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/QPTbxdAbz1M
3. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/api_8h.html
4. https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/faq/

Comment: Almost identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010976/ndk-app-ondestroy-cleanup-how-to-detachcurrentthread/13016133#13016133

Comment: Your edit is basically a new question. Would you be so kind as to answer your question with the threading fix, and make a new question with the login problem? I'd rather post my advice for the login stuff in that question, not this one.

Comment: yeah, thanx, i will do it after i am sure about what i am doing:-)

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved, I used javaVM->GetEnv() to check if the current thread is attached to vm already, instead of attaching the thread directly and get the JNIEnv.

Comment: can you explain a bit more the solution?

Comment: @YashGirdhar   int check = (*Java.jvm)->GetEnv(Java.jvm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
  LOGI("Detach destructor ==: %d", check);
  if (check != JNI_EDETACHED) {
   int detach = (*Java.jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(Java.jvm);

Answer (score 1):

As you only need to detach threads that you have attached you can avoid this problem quite elegantly by using the [tips provided in the Threads section the Android Developer JNI tips page](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#threads). For attaching threads you get called on from a third library it's probably easiest to attach a "before dying" callback on the thread immediately when you have attached it and detach it from there. Something like so (c++ "pseudo"):

```
pthread_key_t CallbackListener::current_env_key;

...

JNIEnv * CallbackListener::getEnv() {
  JNIEnv *env;
  if ((env = (JNIEnv *)pthread_getspecific(current_env_key)) == NULL) {
    env = YourJavaThreadUtils::attachCurrentThreadToJVM(kCallbackThreadName);
    pthread_key_create(&current_env_key, CallbackListener::detach);
    pthread_setspecific(current_env_key, env);
  }
  return env;
}

...

void CallbackListener::detach(void *env) {
  YourJavaThreadUtils::detatchCurrentThreadFromJVM();
}
```